# Automatically downloading libraries for a module

Tags: theming

I have a small module on drupal.org.  Among a few other things, my module adds support for a third-party PHP library to Drupal.  Users are expected to download the module to .../libraries/ and the module provides helper functions, etc.

A few days ago I had a feature request come in.  Essentially, a user is asking for a way to automagically download the PHP library to .../libraries/ for use by the module.

Before I stamp this request as denied, I was curious whether there is a decent method to do this, and if there are any existing modules that already to this (so I can look at them for inspiration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Views Infinite Scroll](http://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) provides a Drush command to do it, so I'd start there- it sounds like a pretty simple option!

> Instead of downloading jquery.autopager manually, drush could be used
>   to download the plugin in /js directory or sites/all/libraries if
>   libraries module is enabled.
>
> Drush command: `drush dl-autopager`

The Drush include is [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/views_infinite_scroll.git/blob/HEAD:/drush/views_infinite_scroll.drush.inc), but this is the important bit:

```
function views_infinite_scroll_drush_autopager_download() {
     if(module_exists('libraries')) {
       $path = 'sites/all/libraries/autopager';

       // Create the path if it does not exist.
       if (!is_dir($path)) {
         drush_op('mkdir', $path);
         drush_log(dt('Directory @path was created', array('@path' => $path)), 'notice');
       }
     }
     else {
       $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'views_infinite_scroll') . '/js';
     }
     drush_op('chdir', $path);
     // Download the plugin.
     if (drush_shell_exec('wget http://jquery-autopager.googlecode.com/files/jquery.autopager-1.0.0.js')) {
       drush_log(dt('jquery.autopager-1.0.0.js has been downloaded to @path', array('@path' => $path)), 'success');
     }
     else {
       drush_log(dt('Drush was unable to download jquery.autopager-1.0.0.js to @path', array('@path' => $path)), 'error');
     }
   }
```

Comment: Oooh.  That is nifty.  Hadn't seen this before.

Comment: @MPD Something like [this](http://drupal.org/node/1841804#comment-6790538) might help ;-)

Comment: Interesting module choice for an example.  I'll check it out.

Comment: @MPD I remember you saying it was yours a fews weeks back - thought I'd check :-p

Answer (score 7):

You can use [drush make](http://drupal.org/project/drush) to do this, but that will only work if the person downloading the module is using drush make.

In your modulename.make file:

```
libraries[foolib][download][type] = "get"
libraries[foolib][download][url] = "http://path.to/file/or/tarball.gz
```

This is only advisable if you are grabbing libraries. Adding dependent modules here currently can cause version conflicts (although many modules supply this info via a modulename.make.example file).

Comment: Definitely +1, but wouldn't it be even better to depend on a library wrapper module, implementing [hook_library](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library/7) or [Libraries equivalent](http://drupal.org/project/libraries), and put the make file in _that_ module.

Comment: Thanks.  Adding an example makefile to the docs was something I hadn't though of.